# Python-pillow install fails, despite required library being available

Tags: python, libraries, synology, pip, ipkg

Good day,

I am using my Synology DS215J as a Python development environment.  I have configured `ipkg` as a system package manager on it.  My goal is to use the Django and Pillow python packages in a virtual environment (Django and virtualenv are already installed through `pip`).  Unfortunately the installation of the Pillow package in my virtual Python environment is failing.

I have installed the required libraries for Pillow through `ipkg`: `libjpeg`, `zlib`, `libtiff`, etc.  I can see they are available in `/usr/lib/`. `libjpeg` is linked to `libjpeg.so.8.0.2`

After activating my virtual environment I try to install Pillow with

```
pip install pillow
```

Pip will download version 3.0.0 and during the installation I get two errors followed by some details on the error:

```
(....)
Failed building wheel for Pillow
(....)
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.

----------------------------------------
Command "/volume2/homes/user/Projects/django_project/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-2daEE8/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NSRCzG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /volume2/homes/user/Projects/django_project/venv/include/site/python2.7/Pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2daEE8/Pillow
```

I am confused to why this fails: the library is available from what I can gather.  What would be my next step to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks

Comment: There is a similar question. The following post may help. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32942958/886607](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32942958/886607)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I had two libjpeg libraries installed: one that was distributed by default and one that was installed with ipkg.  The one that was distributed by default (located in `/usr/lib/`) did not seem to work for the Pillow installation for an unknown reason.  I specified the path of the libjpeg installed by ipkg (`EXPORT LIB="/path/to/library/"`).

Now I run into a problem with ccache so haven't reached my goal yet...